# Get a list of users in the Active directory group using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory

I need your help.
I need a python script that would take a certain group in the Active directory and make a list of users who are in this group.

I have no knowledge with the active directory, I ask for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to win. This code takes a list of users from the group and displays it. In addition, blocked users are not displayed in the list.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM, SUBTREE

ldap_cred = {'server_ip': 'SERVER_IP',
            'user': 'USER_LOGIN',
            'password': 'USER_PASS'}

ldap_conn = Connection(Server(ldap_cred['server_ip']),
                        user=ldap_cred['user'],
                        password=ldap_cred['password'],
                        authentication=NTLM,
                        auto_bind=True)

ldap_users_dir = 'OU=Users,DC=test,DC=local'
ldap_servers_dir = 'OU=Groups,DC=test,DC=local'
user_group = 'GROUP_W_USERS'

def get_group(group_name):
    ldap_conn.search(ldap_servers_dir, '(cn={})'.format(group_name))
    return ldap_conn.response[0]['dn']

def get_users(group_path):
    ldap_conn.search(ldap_users_dir,
        '(&(cn=*)(memberOf={})(objectClass=User)\
        (!(userAccountControl=514))(!(userAccountControl=66050)))'.format(group_path),
        attributes=('sAMAccountName', 'memberof'),
        search_scope=SUBTREE)
    return ldap_conn.entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
    group_p = get_group(user_group)
    for user in get_users(group_p):
        user_n = user.sAMAccountName.value.lower()
        print(user_n)
```

Comment: For me this fails with `ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPUnknownAuthenticationMethodError: NTLM needs domain\username and a password`.